# State of the art approach on a Single Page Dart App & Rest Interface & Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, rest, authentication, dart

After several hours of failing and blog reading I fear the root of my problem is a lack of knowledge on my side :)

I want to authorize Users of my Singe Page Dart App via Spring Security. The Java based server provides some REST services. On working with Spring Security I can provide some JSP login pages - which do not make that much sense in my scenario.

And OAuth is no option in my usecase.

So my question are:

- what is the common way to go here? Should I do a url redirect in my Dart application to a Dart Login site (on requesting secured stuff)?
- Should this Dart Login site call some unsecured LoginController which authorizes the user?

BW Hubert

Answer (score 0):

Just for the protocol I think I found "my way"

- Of course I do a single page application - in fact it's a two page application (meaning the login page is the second...)

  - I did not implement a login controller - a Dart login page does the authentication.

BW Hubert